# How to expand shortcut / shorthand / abbreviation for registry root key to full name, like HKCU to HKEY_CURRENT_USER?

Tags: c#, .net, registry

There are a variety of shorthand for the Registry hive:

- HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT (HKCR)
- HKEY_CURRENT_USER (HKCU)
- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE (HKLM)
- HKEY_USERS (HKU)
- HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG (HKCC)

How can I expand a string like `HKLM` to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`?

The end goal is that i have a list of registry keys which I need to edit.
For example:

```
-path 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Wisp\Touch' -Name 'TouchMode_hold' -value 1
-path 'HKEY_CURRENT_USER:\Software\Microsoft\Wisp\Pen\SysEventParameters' -Name 'HoldMode' -value 1
```

Some of the root keys are in the full form, some are abbreviated. The `Registry` class only accepts full names like (HKEY_CURRENT_USER) so I need to first convert the abbreviation. Regedit.exe accepts both forms - surely there must be a method in the framework somewhere?

Comment: Regedit just has a bunch of "if" statements to recognize the short forms.

Comment: @RaymondChen really? did you decompile the src or something?

Comment: regedit is not written in C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is no builtin way, i decided to go with a helper class instead:

```cs
public static class RegistryHelper
{
    public static string ExpandHiveAbbreviation(string input) 
        => ExpandHiveAbbreviationOrDefault(input) ?? throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(input), input);

    public static bool TryExpandHiveAbbreviation(string input, out string registryHive) => 
        (registryHive = ExpandHiveAbbreviationOrDefault(input)) != null;

    public static string ExpandHiveAbbreviationOrDefault(string input) => 
        input.ToUpperInvariant() switch
        {
            "HKCR" =>"HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT",
            "HKCU" =>"HKEY_CURRENT_USER",
            "HKLM" =>"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE",
            "HKU" =>"HKEY_USERS",
            "HKCC" => "HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG",
            _ => null
        };
}
```